# Set Highcharts column chart in a middle of yAxis?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, visualization, linechart

i have Highcharts chart and i want to add column chart in a middle of yAxis, like that:

## [image]

Is any way to do that using highcharts?

Comment: In general, yes - but it would require semi-official options like axis top, height, left, width. They are not documented in the official API. Those options can be used for positioning axes in the chart (e.g. in the middle) and then you need to assign those axes to the series - see the example http://jsfiddle.net/esadtwg0/

Comment: Thank you very much, i searched it in docs but didn't found